# NullPointerException when importing a package in Weka

Tags: java, plugins, nullpointerexception, weka, package-management

I am developing a plugin for Weka in Java, and I'm  using the [weka/packages/templates](https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/tree/master/packages/templates) to compile and create the package with `ant`. It look like Weka using the weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackage class while importing the packages from the GUI (Tools>PacketManager>File/URL) because when I try to import the resulting zip file in Weka 3.8.6 for Ubuntu, I get a NullPointerException with the following stack trace:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackage.getPackageMetaDataElement(Object)" is null
    at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackage.getDependencies(DefaultPackage.java:252)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageLibIsolatingClassLoader.init(WekaPackageLibIsolatingClassLoader.java:147)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageLibIsolatingClassLoader.<init>(WekaPackageLibIsolatingClassLoader.java:126)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.addPackageToClassLoader(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:369)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.initializeAndLoadUnofficialPackage(WekaPackageManager.java:2372)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.installPackageFromArchive(WekaPackageManager.java:2359)
    at weka.gui.PackageManager$UnofficialInstallTask.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:780)
    at weka.gui.PackageManager$UnofficialInstallTask.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:724)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using OpenJDK 11.0.18 on Ubuntu. Can someone help me understand what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

After reading Weka source code I realized that this error occur while Weka reading depencies needed by the package. In the template file `Descriptions.props` that mean the section "**Dependencies**" are required even if it's not mentioned.

So I add theses lines to fix the problems:

```xml
# Dependencies (format: packageName (equality/inequality version_number)
Depends=weka (>=3.7.12)
```

Comment: Great spotting! We've updated the [Weka wiki](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/packages/structure/#the-description-file) and the LaTeX manuals accordingly.